# Hide the fact a page has been sent a form on reload

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have used a form to submit an image id to the another page.  I have done this rather than r than via url because it makes the url cleaner.  However, when the user now reloads, it asks if they want to submit the form again.  The won't know they have submitted a form, as far as they are aware they have simply clicked an image and been brought to a page that displays that image bigger.

Is there any way around this, that saves the image id the hidden form field has sent via the form, yet refreshes the page for the user?

HTML

```
<a class="gallery-img span4 js-img-submit" href="#">
   <img src="img.jpg"/>
   <form action="/image" method="post">                                
     <input type="hidden" value="<?=$img['id']; ?>" name="image_id"/>
   </form>
</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.js-img-submit').click(function(){           
        $(this).find('form').submit();            
 })
```

PHP

```
$image_id = isset($_POST['image_id']) ? $_POST['image_id'] : false;
```

Comment: @deepu: Its a Form with method post.

Comment: using AJAX may help you

Comment: any downvoter lets put the reason here.

Comment: @Deepu apologies, have added code

Comment: As imsiso said, use jQuery.post to post the id to the backend

Comment: +1 to pikand - using AJAX or `.htaccess` both can help you.

Comment: @imsiso can you answer how to use AJAX for this?  I know i can retrieve things from another script using ajax, but how do I send the user to a page and send a form field value with it?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the parameter needs to be send to the image page.

- GET: You dont want that.
- POST: You use that, but causes the refresh problem.
- SESSION: Will be hidden, but cause troubles, when he opens multiple images, and then refreshing the first page.

So, i would to the following:

Use the hashtag, and load the image via javascript then. finally remove the hashtag:

MainPage:

```
<a class="gallery-img span4 js-img-submit" href="/image#<?=$img['id']; ?>">
   <img src="img.jpg"/>
</a>
```

ImagePage:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var imgid = document.location.hash.slice(1);
   document.location.hash = ""; //Remove
   loadImage(imgid);
})
</script>
```

loadImage then needs to be the required javascript function.

The user might notice it for a split second. IF the user is not allowed to see, then your only way would be to use the PHP Session with seperate variables for every opened image-window.

Comment: thats a good idea.  The only thing is, I want to pass 2 parameters, one the image id, and the other, if the image is available for purchase so ideally i'd want to pass true or false to the script

Comment: you can always extend your hashtag: `image.php#1;true;peter;2012`, and then use `split()` to get the information back.

Comment: ahh, I didn't know oyu could do that

Comment: is this sort of thing not possible with ajax?

Comment: No, the moment you start to render the second page, you cannot access the old one. And if you just make the page call using ajax, you still need to pass a parameter somehow.

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't think I can do this, as I need to get the image id in the php script, not in the js.  It's a wordpress site and it's not so each to get images front end

Comment: If you need the variables in PHP, then you can't use this, yes. Personal recommendation: use GET-Parameters what they are designed for. Don't create additional problems just for a "nicer" url. :-)

Comment: Yes, I think I do.  They just look ugly.

Comment: well, you could make look it "nicer" by using a htaccess file and rewrite an url like `image/2015/4` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.js-img-submit').click(function()
{           
    $.post("image.php", {id: $(this).find('input').val()});                
})
```